# Combining Application and Server Level logging with Log4J?

Tags: java, properties, log4j

Is it possible to work with two different levels of logging simultaneously with Log4J/Tomcat? Here is my situation: I have a few webapps operating on the same Tomcat Server. Some of these applications have their own log4j properties file (legacy).

Something I want to add is a new logger with a JDBCAppender that will work across all of these applications (They're meant to be used together so having them log to the db we've selected would be VERY useful for us.) I've written the properties file entries in order to do this the way I want (and tested in one of those local property files for syntax purposes).

Is it possible to drop this new logger/JDCBAppender in a server-level log4j.properties file, and then have the webapps gain access to it? For instance, if I define the logger as 'com.xxx.yyy', then in any webapp that has a class in a 'com.xxx.yyy' package grab said logger with a call like:

```
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

assuming the full declaration is com.xxx.yyy.MyClass.

I've tried dropping the log4j.properties file in the `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` directory as well as placing the necessary jar files in the same directory (as directed in the comments below) but when I launch my server, it doesn't seem to pick that one up, although it picks up the one from my webapp. I know the properties file has to be on the classpath for log4j to pick it up, but can there be some sort of similar-class path style issue if there is more than one log4j.properties file?

**Update: I've updated the description of what I've tried.**

Comment: You need more steps for make tomcat to use log4j http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some additional research and learned that if multiple log4j.properties files are on the classpath, the system will use the first it finds, just like with java class/library files.

So in the end, the situation I was describing is not feasible, as adding a Server-level properties file would cause all my individual web-apps' legacy property files to be ignored. It may still be possible to do something similar, but my question was intended to focus specifically on the log4j.properties file.